# DbAdapter class versus ContentProvider whats the difference in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to find out what is the difference between setting up the database through DbAdapter class or setting up everything in Content Provider ?

Is it true that the DbAdapter class is more of a temporary stopgap while the ContentProvider is a long term solution that allows more functionalities such as search capability and stuff ?

Can an instance of the Dbadapter class be built within the ContentProvider ? such that I actually can just call and manage everything from the DB straight from the Provider class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend investing some time learning how to write a ContentProvider. They are a little daunting at first but once you've mastered the concept you'll get payback bigtime; especially if you're creating a moderately complex app.

When using a ContentProvider:

- Content providers can be used from
  other processes and are required by
  some mechanisms on Android like the
  global search
- Other apps will be able
  to access your data.
- You can wrap and
  abstract a lot of the query logic in
  your content provider, and limit
  access.
- You will be able to lean on
  the system to allow for things like
  managed queries.

Indeed the ContentProvider is a wrapper around your DBAdapter providing standard method such as query, update, delete etc.

Here is a good tutorial:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/

Comment: Hey damian thanks ! OMG these is indeed the kind of answers android.developer should be putting up so that first time learners have a good idea of whats impt and whats not ! THanks Damian once again !